# I cant fix OAuth2 verification in app script

Tags: google-apps-script

So I'm a newbie and I'm trying to write code to work in Google App Script and its for cannibalization. I've been stuck on it for a couple of days as I cannot fix the issue with OAuth2 it's giving me in a few lines and i have no idea what to do anymore. here is my entire code:

function main() {

```
const domainName = 'domain.name';
const website = `https://${domainName}/`;
const domain = `${domainName}_${today}`;
const libraryKey = 'YOUR_LIBRARY_KEY';  // Replace with your actual library key
const library = 'YOUR_LIBRARY_ID';  // Replace with your actual library ID
const url = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token';
const scope = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request'
].join(' ');
const keyFileLocation = 'token.json'; // Note: You'll need to use a different method to handle auth in Apps Script.
const serviceAccountKey = 'YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY'; // Replace with your actual service account key

const authorization = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
const propertyUrl = 'domain.name';

let working = true;
const rowLimit = 25000;
let index = 0;
let answer = {};

while (working) {
    const request = {
        'startDate': ninetyDaysAgo,
        'endDate': yesterday,
        'dimensions': ["query", "page"],
        'rowLimit': rowLimit,
        'startRow': rowLimit * index
    };
    const service = getOAuthService('YOUR_WEB_CLIENT_SERVICE_KEY', ['placeholder']);  // Replace with your actual web client service key
    const results = executeRequest(getWebmastersService(service), website, request);

    if (results.rows) {
        results.rows.forEach(function (row) {
            const query = row.keys[0];
            const url = row.keys[1];
            const impressions = row.impressions;
            const clicks = row.clicks;
            const position = Math.round(row.position * 100) / 100;
            const ctr = Math.round(row.ctr * 10000) / 100;

            if (!answer[query]) {
                answer[query] = [[url, impressions, clicks, position, ctr]];
            } else {
                answer[query].push([url, impressions, clicks, position, ctr]);
            }
        });

        index++;
    } else {
        working = false;
    }
}

const fileName = `cannibalization_${domain}.tsv`;
let fileContent = 'query\tcount\turl\tposition\timpression\tclicks\tctr\n';
for (let key in answer) {
    if (answer[key].length > 1) {
        answer[key].forEach(function (row) {
            fileContent += `${key}\t${answer[key].length}\t${row[0]}\t${row[3]}\t${row[1]}\t${row[2]}\t${row[4]}\n`;
        });
    }
}
```

}

```
function getOAuthService(keyFileLocation, scopes) {
return OAuth2.createService('Web')  // Assuming it's a web client application
    .setClientId('YOUR_CLIENT_ID')  // Replace with your actual client ID
    .setClientSecret('YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET')  // Replace with your actual client secret
    .setRedirectUri('YOUR_REDIRECT_URI')  // Replace with your actual redirect URI
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
    .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
    .setPrivateKey(serviceAccountKey)
    .setIssuer('placeholder')
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
    .setScope(scopes);
```

}

```
function getWebmastersService(authenticatedService) {
return authenticatedService.createService('webmasters')
    .setVersion('v3');
```

}

I replaced some sensitive info with placeholders. Please tell me what i did wrong?

im trying with gpt but cant do it